# Spring Security: Java Config: How to add the method type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, config

I'm using Spring Securitys Java Config.

Want to translate the following **XML**:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" method="POST" />
```

Got it working with **Java Config**:

```
http.authorizeUrls().antMatchers("/login").permitAll();
```

But one problem is there:

I can still use  "/login" with a Browser and do a GET-Request. But I only want that the url can be accessed by POST.

**Quesion:**

How can I add this  >> method="POST" << to java configuration?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you'd check the documentation of [antMatchers](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherConfigurer.html#antMatchers%28org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,%20java.lang.String...%29) method, you will see that enumeration of [HttpMethod](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpMethod.html?is-external=true) can be passed as the first parameter.

So something like this should work:

```
http.authorizeUrls().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll();
```

Comment: Do you know maybe how to add allowed POST and GET endpoints? Because invoking:

`.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/some-other").permitAll()`

Does not work. The POST to /login seems to be overwritten since I get 403 on it.

Comment: updated antMatcher url?  http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html#AntPathRequestMatcher-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: FYI `authorizeUrls()` does not exist in latest version of Spring Security. Use `authorizeRequests()`