# Query about storing some data and securing the application Angular-SpringBoot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, redux, ngrx-store

I'm learning and developing an application using Angular 4 - Spring Boot with REST webservices. The database being used is MS SQL Server 2016. Now I'm new to this world of web development using Angular so have few questions. I apologise if they are noobish.

1. In Java we used to have `Session` to store some stuff like `username` and all. In here I'm using `Local Storage` but in some data like lists or arrays of objects I'm facing issue of synchronization across all components. Then I came across `Redux`. So can I solve my problem by storing my data using redux?
2. For securing my application I was thinking of using JSON Web Tokens. My understanding is that I have to encode my REST webservices from Spring end and then decode it with at Angular side. is my understanding correct ? If yes, then how do I decode it at Angular side?

Thanks a ton for all the help :)

Comment: 1. If you have bugs with simple code using LocalStorage, using an additional layer of complexity won't help. You need to understand, and fix the bugs. 2. "encoding REST services" doesn't mean anything. A JWT is just some piece of information created by the server, sent to the client at authentication time (typically), and sent back from the client to the server as a cookie or a header. I don't see what encoging or decoding (whatever that means) has to do with that.

Comment: What about oauth  based authentication in spring?? Where you must have 2 applications: 1. An oAuth based server application(stateless server), 2. A client application(front end with local user session) interacting with server using token(jwt or whatever you want)

Comment: @JBNizet And here I thought that the JSON data that the Spring REST web service is generating will be encoded using JWT. Looks like I'm way off the track

Comment: @Afridi I think OAuth is paid right? My application has to be on open source technologies and libraries only, sort of a constraint here.

Comment: @TweaknFreak no, OAuth libraries are totally free provided by Spring (boot). Check this for configuring oauth 2.0 in spring(boot)
http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs

Comment: @Afridi, Thanks for that. Another question, suppose I have a REST web service exposing data from a table to a url - `hhtp://localhost:8080/api/data_endpoint/all` . Now if someone knows this exact URL then he can access the data and modify the table using PUT or POST or DELETE. Can I prevent this in some possible way?

Comment: @TweaknFreak you can handle this using spring security up to some extents by adding method type as well along with endpoint authentication. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399433/spring-security-java-config-how-to-add-the-method-type

Answer (score 0):

My solutions

1. Use session storage in browser and store values as encrypted values in session.
2. Implemented JWT with AES encryption so as to protect token generated from unauthorized data access.